# Standalone CMake script to cut off file contents by delimiters

Tags: cmake

I have a project where one repeatable task to do involves manipulating files' contents.
Until now I used a Python script for it, but recently I discovered I can use standalone CMake scripts ("standalone" here means they can be invoked outside of configure/build/test/etc. workflow). As my project already uses CMake for project management I concluded I can save others' problem of installing a Python interpreter (welcome Windows users!) and use CMake project-wide.

Part of my script needs to read a file and cut off everything that appears before "[START-HERE]" and after "[END-HERE]" lines. I am stuck with that part and don't know how to implement it. How can it be done?

Comment: Why not invoke a `powershell` script? Not everything has to be CMake. You can invoke both `.bat` and `.ps` files from CMake and using CMake for this is just pointless? I don't think it will help anyone.

Comment: @MilanŠ. Is PowerShell cross-platform and out-of-box with CMake?

Comment: @user did OP mention anything about cross-platform? IIRC he welcomed Windows users. On Linux you can do the same with bash. And last I recalled Powershell **is crossplatform**

Comment: I interpret "_welcome Windows users!_" as "you're welcome, Windows users!"- in which case, it would be assumed that windows users are not the only users. Also, the post says "_save others' problem of installing a Python interpreter_". So even if PowerShell is cross-platform, that doesn't solve the problem of avoiding requiring some users to install things- assuming my interpretation of "welcome" is correct.

Comment: @user Ok great, write it in `bash script` then. If you're on linux .. you don't even need git, but if you're on windows and you use git, then you have a bash emulator that can execute the scripts. Much better for the task then CMake and if you don't see that then I don't know what to say.

Comment: As a side note, powershell even allows you to "enable bash" and invoke the scripts without git.

Comment: @MilanŠ. does that involve installing WSL?

Comment: @user no, you don't need WSL to run bash scripts on windows. I do it regularly with my custom git hooks. Maybe if you don't install git then yes, but who doesn't use git nowadays?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251531/discussion-between-user-and-milan-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine [`file(READ)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#read) with [`if(MATCHES)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#matches) to accompilish this. The former is used to read the file, the latter allows you to check for the occurance of a regular expression and to extract a capturing group:

**foo.cmake**

```
#[===[
Params:
INPUT_FILE : the path to the file to read
#]===]

file(READ "${INPUT_FILE}" FILE_CONTENTS)

if (FILE_CONTENTS MATCHES "(^|[\r\n])\\[START-HERE\\][\r\n]+(.*)[\r\n]+\\[END-HERE\\]")
    # todo: use extracted match stored in CMAKE_MATCH_2 for your own logic
    message("Content: '${CMAKE_MATCH_2}'")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "[START-HERE]...[END-HERE] doesn't occur in the input file '${INPUT_FILE}'")
endif()
```

**foo.txt**

```
Definetly not
[START-HERE]
working
[END-HERE]
Try again!
```

Output:

```
> cmake -D INPUT_FILE=foo.txt -P foo.cmake
Content: 'working'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the part where you are stuck, here's one approach using the [`string`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html), [`file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html), and [`math`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/math.html) commands:

```
file(READ data.txt file_str)
string(FIND "${file_str}" "[START-HERE]" start_offset)
# message("${start_offset}")
math(EXPR start_offset "${start_offset}+12")
# message("${start_offset}")
string(FIND "${file_str}" "[END-HERE]" end_offset)
math(EXPR substr_len "${end_offset}-${start_offset}")
# message("${substr_len}")
string(SUBSTRING "${file_str}" "${start_offset}" "${substr_len}" trimmed_str)
# message("${trimmed_str}")
```

You could also probably do it by using the [`file(STRINGS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#strings) command, which reads lines of a file into an array, and then use the [`list(FIND)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#find) command. The approach shown above has the advantage of working if your delimiters are not on their own lines.

As [@fabian](/users/2991525) shows in [their answer post](/a/75303245/11107541), you can also do this using a regular expression with [`if(MATCHES)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#matches) like this:

> ```
> file(READ "${INPUT_FILE}" FILE_CONTENTS)
>
> if (FILE_CONTENTS MATCHES "(^|[\r\n])\\[START-HERE\\][\r\n]+(.*)[\r\n]+\\[END-HERE\\]")
>     # todo: use extracted match stored in CMAKE_MATCH_2 for your own logic
>     message("Content: '${CMAKE_MATCH_2}'")
> else()
>     message(FATAL_ERROR "[START-HERE]...[END-HERE] doesn't occur in the input file '${INPUT_FILE}'")
> endif()
> ```